# how can I get XmlNodes data with XmlDocument in similar node name?

Tags: c#, xml

my xml data is :

```
<response>
<result name="response" numFound="2" start="0">
<doc><str name="Author">ALi Ahmadi</str><int name="BookID">1904</int><str name="Title">BookName 1</str></doc>
<doc><str name="Author">Reza Javadi</str><int name="BookID">1523</int><str name="Title">BookName 2</str></doc>
</result>
</response>
```

my c# code is :

```
XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDoc.LoadXml(ResultData);

XmlNodeList XnList = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("/response/result/doc");
foreach (XmlNode Xn in XnList)
{
    string a = Xn["str"].InnerText;
    string b = Xn["int"].InnerText;
    string c = Xn["str"].InnerText;
    //string c = Xn["str[@name='Title']"].InnerText;//error !
}
```

a & c result is : "Ali Ahmadi", How can i get "BookName 1" in c variable ?

Comment: doc has 3 Elements- a str, with Attribute Name="Author", an int, with Attribute Name="BookID", and a str, with Attribute Name "Title". That's ALMOST pseudocode in itself ;)

Comment: How can I get Author & Title Content?

Comment: why did you use two tags 'str' in one doc element ?

Comment: How can I get content of xmlnode with "Title" attribute name ? (For example : Xn["str[@name='Title']"].InnerText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you know the index of the node 'Title' 
you can get it's inerrHTML via this code:

```
     c = Xn.ChildNodes[2].InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 string c = Xn["str"].Attributes["Title"].Value
```

Comment: It's wrong : (error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Comment: check Attributes["Author"].Value instead of Attributes["Title"].Value

Comment: hmm..actually why have you used two <str> tags?

Comment: I get response of solr search engine in asp.net that content of result is xml. I can't change it, then, I want get content of it. Ok ?